# Как сделать курсор сервера видимым на удаленной машине. Использую VNC

Tags: linux, vnc

У меня есть одноплатник с `Linux'ом` и `vnc` сервером, а в качестве дисплея использую iPad.

Дело в том что мышь подключена к одноплатнику и на iPad'е она не отображается, как и не отображается на любой другой машине соответственно.
Как я понял, это вынужденное ограничение протокола `vnc`, он передает данные не целой картинкой а блоками и для этого мышь сервера сделали невидимой, что-бы снизить нагрузку на канал.

Вопрос в том можно ли это как-то изменить? Я перепробовал разные клиент-сервер с разными конфигурациями но так и не добился результата.

Comment: Какой клиент, какой сервер? VNC всегда прекрасно передавал и передаёт курсор мыши, видимо у вас какие-то проблемы с настройкой программ

Comment: @andreymal Сервер Xtightvnc, клиент VNC Viewer. Даже встроенный клиент macOS не видит его, значит проблема в сервере!?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отображался курсор, нужно собрать свежую версию x11vnc

```
git clone git@github.com:LibVNC/x11vnc.git
cd x11vnc
sudo apt-get install libvncserver-dev
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Источник: https://github.com/kbumsik/VirtScreen/issues/19#issuecomment-429573666